# org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter in eclipse create server error

Tags: struts2

I had found that whenever i am using `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` class in `web.xml` file , it gives me error

> 'Staring tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost ' has encountered a problem. Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

I am using struts 2.5.10.1 version
I had seen and tried all the solutions about this problem but nothing work for me. Please help I am trying to solve this from past 2 days.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886252/filter-startup-exception-for-struts-2

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Struts2 are you using? This is the current path of the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: Sorry i had wrongly written .nd . I am using struts 2.5.10.1 version